# Accessing localhost shows 404 on IIS 7.5 webserver. Where are the logs?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

Wanted to access a local website by

```
http://127.0.0.1/
http://localhost/
http://192.x.x.x/
```

but the only reply from any browser was:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Thu, 03 Oct 2013 09:38:48 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 315
```

There is nothing in the logs about what was wrong with the request

```
  %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC3
  %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles
```

To solve the problem and access the website added 'localhost', 127... in IIS bindings for this website. Pages are served using these local Urls.

Requests arrived to IIS since as soon as defined the bindings requests are served.

My question: Is there a log or way to trace what was happening with the request before defined localhost binding in IIS? What is returning the 404?

Comment: Any default pages in IIS and your root dir? Default.aspx, for example.

Comment: Open your IIS, choose your site, choose browse. It should open your site. And look at the Url. What it shows?

Comment: Yes, there are the 'default' default pages defined in IIS and I can navigate to default.aspx. But my question is not how to make this work, is already working. My question is about to find how to trace what is replying to my request.

Comment: You may look at routing handlers,  httpModules. It will give you a chance to break point before you get 404. And, events in Global.asax?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable failed request tracing on the server and on the site and add a tracing rule to capture 404 requests. That will tell  you exactly what the issues is